# rewrite module is not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple piece pf code. I want to enter some word in URL and wants that it should stay on the same page. 
My index.php file is

```
 <?php

    echo "sample test";

 ?>
```

My htaccess file is

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
  RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$index.php?url=$1[L,QSA]
```

Both file are placed in the kite folder of wamp directory.
When I type localhost/kite then the index page appears. But when i write something more after kite for example localhost/kite/about then it says requested url is not found. 
I have turned on all rewrite_module in wamp.

Comment: Your code is invalid. `RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d` should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$index.php?url=$1[L,QSA]` should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: i will check this code sir

Comment: its still not working Mike

Comment: Write something wrong to your htaccess file, like "abc, xyz" in the beginning of htaccess, if you open index page and it shows 500 error, that means AllowOverride is not active for your DocumentRoot. Check Apache configure.

Answer (score 1):

The following is correct and working. You were almost there, your spacing was just off a little.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Then your rewrite_module must not be active. Try typing garbage into your .htaccess file, like "blah blah blah" and if you don't get an http error (as opposed to the normal "page not found"), then you know the .htaccess file is not being read.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```